# Can you define your own Namespace Separator in PHP?

Tags: php, namespaces

Example using Namespace in PHP...

```
use \MyLibrary\Registry;
use \MyLibrary\User;
use \MyLibrary\Request;

namespace MyLibrary\Base
{
    class Base
    {
        public $registry;

        function __construct($registry)
        {
            $this->registry = $registry;
            $this->user = New User;
            $this->request = new Request;
            # code...
        }
    }
}
```

Now in C# the Namespace separator is more like this...

```
using MyLibrary.Registry;
using MyLibrary.User;
using MyLibrary.Request;

namespace MyLibrary.Base
{
    public partial class Base
    {
        public MyFunction(registry)
        {
            Code here
        }
    }
}
```

So I know there is a lot of complaints on the PHP namespace separator, so bad that some people don't even use them because they hate the current backslash.

So I am curious, is there any way possible to Define your own Namespace separator to be used in PHP?

Comment: Sure - just rewrite PHP.

Comment: You probably by recompiling PHP but sincerely `\\` is just fine

Comment: Ha! You wish. I believe there were some discussions about making that syntax abomination configurable per `php.ini`.  But no, stuck with backslash until a PHP successor language comes around.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a decent, well presented question.

Comment: @TimCooper cause its ugly and hard to press on keyboard..plain simple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't, it's hard-wired into the language.  Such a thing would be really difficult to do anyway, as other symbols already have meanings assigned to them in PHP (. is string concatinate, / is divide, * is multiply, etc).

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa It is.  Unfortunately it's also the namespace character and no wanting it not to be will cause it not to be. I never said it was a good choice :)  Because the \ character for escaping only ever happens in strings I guess they thought they could get away with it.  The same isn't true of the other characters I mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

No is not an answer. It's just a matter of overhead of course. Apart from the mentioned redeclaration at compile time, you could use a preprocessor for the desired effect. (Just the effect, not an actual language change.)

There is for exmaple [`pihipi`](http://www.google.com/search?q=pihipi) which defined a standard C++ esque namespace separator before PHP 5.3 did. And as second example there is the [`phpp` preprocessor](http://nanoserv.si.kz/downloads/nanoserv-2.1.1.tgz), albeit that only allows to enable/disable namespaces.

Using `.` like in Java-class languages is a bit ambigious and cannot be reasonably emulated in a preprocessor. It's borderline feasible at runtime, but not in PHP, and not without concessions about the distinct identifier planes. Using `::` would be doable, but nobody has bothered yet. (Maybe the Quercus PHP implementation tried, not sure.)

Comment: What's with your second link? File download?

Comment: Yeah, it's a download (of something else no less). Didn't find a specific repository for it.